# Spring Boot test class wont inject beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am using the following dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

 compile("com.caucho:resin-hessian:4.0.23")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.0.RELEASE')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:1.2.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
    compile('org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-manager:1.3.0.RELEASE') {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
    //SI
    compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:$springIntegrationVersion")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.2.0.RELEASE')
```

Created new test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:**/*.xml"})
@ComponentScan({"com.mycompany.notification.processor.service"})
public class DownloadFileTaskletTest  {

    @Autowired
     private DownloadFileTasklet downloadFileTasklet;

    @Test
    public void execute()
    {
        System.out.printf("test123");

    }
}
```

I created test case inside Spring boot
However i get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batch.DownloadFileTaskletTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.notification.processor.service.batch.tasks.DownloadFileTasklet batch.DownloadFileTaskletTest.downloadFileTasklet; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mycompany.notification.processor.service.batch.tasks.DownloadFileTasklet] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This is my application class:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.mycompany.notification.processor.service"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
        "classpath:integration-context.xml","classpath:launch-context.xml","classpath:applicationContext-NotificationProcessorService.xml"
})
//@Import({ ServletConfiguration.class, WebappConfiguration.class })
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.printf("hello man");
    }

}
```

Any idea why I cant inject beans into my test class?

I removed @ContextConfiguration,@ComponentScan,@IntegrationTes as suggested
Now I see different exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:160)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration or @ContextHierarchy.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:57)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: For starters remove the `@ContextConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` from your test clase, those don't make sense. Also `@IntegrationTest` serves a different purpose so I would expect you wouldn't need that.

Comment: Done. I edited my question and added the new exception

Comment: Please be aware that I have serverl applicationContext in my resources that I need to load

Comment: No you don't as those are loaded by Spring Boot, you have the `ImportResource` on your `Application` class.

Comment: The exception doesn't make sense as `@RunWith` together with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` should be enough to run your tests. As explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications) in the reference guide.

Comment: You don't by anychange have added your test class as a bean to the configuration have you?

Comment: Nope. I havnt. my test test class is under test directory and batch package

Comment: What package is the Application class in?

Comment: The src package is on  com.mycompany.notification.processor and test package is under batch

Answer (score 10):

just remove this part:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

instead ,using this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This was the solution that I required after following this tutorial: http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/